# Username field in registration form

Tags: forms, registration, username

I have a registration form with:

```
username
email
password
captcha
```

I am thinking about remove the username field and generate something like `username_123` and then give the opportunity to the user change his username later. Right now the field username is required.

However, I have the fear of majority of the users not changing the default username. My fear is that some of my users won't know what to put in that field, so I'll have some bad usernames like `testtest` or `test`. Unfortunately, getting part of email as username is not an option, too invasive in this particular case.

Should it be something that's required or should I generate a username for my users?

Comment: Is the username field required to log-in, or just a handle so they don't publish the e-mail to other users?

Comment: What's the problem with usernames like "testtest" and "test"? Is there some sort of data issues there?

Comment: just to echo what the others have said: would like to know what the username is used for. why does the user need it etc?

Comment: @hd. the username is just a persona for comments or posts, not used to login.

Comment: @AndrewMartin Is not a real problem in terms of functionality, but is strange to chat with an user called test, right? But well, is strange to talk with user455318 too and stackoverflow does the same.

Comment: What's the difference between letting the user pick a name at registration vs setting it later?  They can still just change their name to "test".  Also, why do you think your users will pick names like that?  You can disable specific screen names that you don't want.

Comment: @puhlen Setting later will remove one field in registration form. In my case means -25% stuff to fill. Of course he can set the username to test or similar after the registration. Also, I am sure they will pick, because I already have users with that usernames and some suggestions from real users to remove it from registration.

Comment: It might be clearer if you distinguish between a username and a display name. There's a lot of confusion generated by calling a display name a username.

Comment: You want to remove one field from your sign-up form (25% of the fields!), you want a nice, displayable username not based on private info. I guess you could try ESP. You cannot make a task arbitrarily simple and still end up with meaningful information, something has to go.

Comment: *However, I have the fear of majority of the users not changing the default username.* - looking at [your own username](http://ux.stackexchange.com/users/87264/user455318), the fear seems legitimate.

Comment: Reminds me of Xbox's Gamer Tags...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

having autogenerated user name is probably not good idea as they may forget it.

Let them choose a username.

Comment: If they can login with an email address, is this a problem?

Comment: The username could be autogenerated but changeable possibly. And if email is also a valid login identifier then autogeneration with or without changeable username is irrelevant.

Answer (score 8):

Why not use their email address as their username, like thousands of sites do?

If you need them to choose a username at a later date you can provide a screen for doing so and guide them to create one and let them know where it will be used across the site, like a message board.

Comment: I don't want to disclose the email, or part of the email. simple as that. Privacy concerns

Comment: You're not disclosing it, you're using it to log in.

Comment: No, I need the username to identify each user in plataform, similar to stackoverflow or reddit. The username is a public persona. To login I use the email.

Comment: You're not reading what I wrote.

Comment: I am reading but unfortunately i don't understand your point.

Comment: You're suggesting that they need to provide a username up front, I agree, as do most of the people answering your question, that it is unnecessary. Have them login - with their email address then provide a screen for them to create a username, but pre-populate it with a default value. However, you don't say what the username is for, so it sounds superfluous.

Comment: So, exactly like Stack Exchange, where you login with your e-mail (or Google or Facebook ID) but it is kept private and replaced with a default screen name like user455318?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: No, he says it should be asked for when it's needed - not generated.

Comment: @Darryl: You should extend your answer. It's really better than the accepted one, but looks like people misunderstand it.

Answer (score 4):

As the username is a handle by which the user will be known, you should make it easy for them to change it.  Why not copy stackexchange? Prefill with a userID like `user12345` (which may be related to your users table key field), but put the focus in the prefilled box (maybe even select the username) for the user to type their real name.  (This is approximate, it's a long time since I created my logon here). If the user wants to be called "Test" let them -- for all you know it's their real name just from a culture you don't know.  For that matter if they want to be called "WhyShouldITypeInThisStupidBox" it's up to them.

Comment: Elsewhere on se there's someone using the handle "Suspended User" -- it might be confusing but it's not a real problem.

Answer (score 2):

Indicate to the user that whatever they put in the username input will be what they'll be shown as to other users. This will influence their decision and they can decide if they want to make it something weird ("sdfhsdiohspd") or something personal to them ("Frank").

If the username has already been taken, and your application *needs* the username to be unique, inform the user or give them some alternatives, much like Google does on signup.

[image]

Also, you seem cautious on what the username can be, so you *could* create a blacklist of words, but I don't think it'll be foolproof, and people will find ways around it by using things such as [Leet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leet), or "impersonating" letters (ie: uppercase `i` becoming lowercase `l`). You could try adding in filters using [MauriceButler/badwords](https://github.com/MauriceButler/badwords) or [LDNOOBW/List-of-Dirty-Naughty-Obscene-and-Otherwise-Bad-Words](https://github.com/LDNOOBW/List-of-Dirty-Naughty-Obscene-and-Otherwise-Bad-Words) to prevent people "cheating the system" - but then you could fall victim to the [Scunthorpe problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem).

In conclusion, keep the username box if you don't want to publish the users e-mail and let them decide on what the username should be.

The user should have the freedom to decide how they're recognised by others and how personal the recognition should be.

Comment: I haven't tested here or at Wikipedia, but I *think* that certainly in the latter case usernames are forbidden from using obscenities only by policy and a way to flag for the admins.  After all, *defamatory* usernames don't have to involve bad words to have an impact.

Answer (score 1):

This will depend on how important is the persona in your site.

If the site importance doesn't rely on ("verified") relation between users or if whom is writing the content is less important than the content itself, maybe it is alright to give the user an auto-generated username on sign up.

### Give both options:

**Automatically suggested username or Custom username.**

If you want to go for auto-generated usernames on sign-up, give the user the option to enter a custom username if he doesn't want an auto-generated one. **This way you remove the step for the user of changing his username after he is being assigned one.**

Answer (score 0):

Auto-generated usernames are used in registration forms where entering a username is optional, and can be later changed. If your form requires username better don't generate it.

Here are some reasons:

- you're **violating the usability heuristic** "[Support internal locus of control](https://faculty.washington.edu/jtenenbg/courses/360/f04/sessions/schneidermanGoldenRules.html)"
- **interaction cost is increased** because the user have to delete the autogenerated username.
- novice users might think that the username could not be changed
- users might forget the username *@colmcq*

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned above in a comment, let the users use their email ID to login into the system.

As for the system identifying the users, it's probably a good idea to take an approach similar to [what Facebook does](https://www.facebook.com/help/211813265517027). Facebook generates a string of random numbers assigned to the user as the username, and replaces it with a chosen string if the user decides to set a specific user name for himself / herself. Since the user is not using the username to log into the system, even if he / she does not choose to customize it, they have no need to know of it.